# Ошибка при установке pip3 install mysql-python

Tags: mysql, python, pip

Только на днях использовал данную библиотеку - всё было нормально, но столкнулся с тем, что пришлось переустановить ОС.

Выдает данную ошибку: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-na6z6suw/mysql-python/`

Гугление подсказала, мол данная библиотека не поддерживается в Python 3, но ведь же я до этого времени использовал. Все подобные ответы, кстати, смежные с джанго.

Comment: Покажите сообщение об ошибке полностью - то, что вы скопировали не говорит ровным счетом ни о чем. Также приведите код команды, которую выполняли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте PyMysql, использую у себя в Django проекте

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb1 (mysql-python) не поддерживал, не поддерживает и не будет поддерживать Python 3, последний апдейт на него (mysql-python) вышел в 2014 году

Можете попробовать [mysqlclient-python](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python), это форк MySQLdb1 с поддержкой Python 3